# How can I read data from a file into a vector of class without using getLine()?

Tags: c++

I have some data in the file that I would like to be able to read into a vector of a class-type/object. This object also has within itself a vector that takes in another class type, and the data that needs to populate that inner vector is also contained within the text file. How can I read the data from the file into the vectors accordingly without using getLine()?

The data is formatted as so in the document.

```
143 Jones
1234        2   C
-1

123 Smith
4321        4   A
132     3   B
-1
```

Where the first line is the ID of the student followed by their name, and below it is a series of classes that student has taken followed by the number of credits each course is worth and the grade the student got for the course.

Below is the course class header code

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>

class Course {
    public:
        Course(int, int, std::string);
        int getCourseCode() const {return courseCode;}
        int getCredits() const {return courseCredits;}
        std::string getGrade() const {return grade;}
        void print(std::ostream &os) const;

    private:
        int courseCode;
        int courseCredits;
        std::string grade;
};

inline std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &os, const Course &course) {
    course.print(os); 
    
    return os;
}

inline Course::Course(int courseCode, int courseCredits, std::string grade) {
    this->courseCode = courseCode;
    this->courseCredits = courseCredits;
    this->grade = grade;
}
```

Below is the student class header code

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include "course.h"

class Student {
    public:
        Student(int, std::string, std::vector<Course> courses);
        int getID() const;
        double getGPA() const;
        std::string getName() const;
        void print(std::ostream &os) const;
        std::vector<Course> courses;

    private:
        int id;
        std::string name;
};

inline std::ostream &operator << (std::ostream &os, const Student &student) {
    student.print(os);

    return os;
}
```

Below is the student.cpp code

```
#include "student.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;

Student::Student(int id, std::string name, vector<Course> courses) {
    this->id = id;
    this->name = name;
    this->courses = courses;
}

int Student::getID() const {
    return id;
}

string Student::getName() const {
    return name;
}

double Student::getGPA() const {
    double total;
    double creds;
    double cgrade;
    double gpa;

    for(int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++) {
        if(courses[i].getGrade() == "A") cgrade = 4.0;
        else if(courses[i].getGrade() == "B") cgrade = 3.0;
        else if(courses[i].getGrade() == "C") cgrade = 2.0;
        else if(courses[i].getGrade() == "D")cgrade = 1.0;

        total += cgrade * courses[i].getCredits();
        creds += courses[i].getCredits();
    }

    gpa = total / creds;

    return gpa;
}

void Student::print(std::ostream &os) const {
    os << id << " " << name << ": " << this->getGPA() << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < courses.size(); i++) {
        os << courses[i];
    }
}
```

This is what I've tried so far in terms of trying to load the vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "student.h"

using namespace std;

void loadStudents(string fileName, vector<Student> &students);
bool compareCourses(const Course &c1, const Course &c2);
bool compareStudents(const Student &s1, const Student &s2);
void printResults(string fileName, vector<Student> &students);

int main() {
    try {
        vector<Student> students;

        loadStudents("students.data", students);

        cout << students.size() << " records processed" << endl;

        return 0;
    }
    catch(string message) {
        cout << "Error: " << message << endl;
        exit(1);
    }
};

void loadStudents(string fileName, vector<Student> &students) {
    ifstream studentsFile(fileName.c_str());
    if(!studentsFile.good()) {
        throw string("Input file: " + fileName + ", not found!");
    }

    int id;
    string name;
    vector<Course> cs;

    while(studentsFile >> id >> name >> cs) {
        students.place_back(student);
    }

    studentsFile.close();
}

bool compareCourses(const Course &c1, const Course &c2) {
    return c1.getGrade() < c2.getGrade();
}

bool compareStudents(const Student &s1, const Student &s2) {
    return s1.getGPA() < s2.getGPA();
}

void printResults(string fileName, vector<Student> &students) {
    ofstream outputFile(fileName.c_str());
    if(!outputFile.good()) {
        throw string("Output file: " + fileName + ", not found!");
    }

    for(auto student : students) {
        outputFile << student.print(outputFile) << endl;
    }

    outputFile.close();
}
```

I'm getting an error stating that "no operator ">>" matches these operands" in the while loop inside the loadStudents function, which I think pertains to the istream for the vector.

The desired output is something like this printed to an output file.

```
143 Smith: 3.57143
        4321 (4 credits): A
        132 (3 credits): B
143 Jones: 2
        1234 (2 credits): C

2 records processed
```

Where the student ID and name are printed along with their calculated GPA and the courses they took below them followed by a message stating the number of students that were processed.

My main issue pertains to the loading of the students vector with the subsequent data of the course information being appropriately loaded into the courses vector for each student. Is this possible without using the getLine() method and istream >>?

Comment: This may be possible without using getline() but its likely not a better solution. Is there some reason why you can not use getline?

Comment: If you can't use `getLine`, use `getline`.

Comment: @drescherjm Basically I was instructed to not use getLine or any other line oriented I/O, but to stick to token oriented I/O like >>

Comment: `>>` is tricky since its default behaviour is to discard whitespace, making it impossible for your code to know whether or not the token ended with a space, a tab or sundry other whitespace characters including the end of line. But if you play around with [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) you'll quickly find your way onto a good path. Once you're there,  it might be worth your time to write your own version of `getline`. Might make other parts of the job easier.